# Why is the cos, sin definition of the unit circle true?

Tags: trigonometry, unit-of-measure

So imagine we have a unit circle and there a point $M$ on it. Then the $x$ coordinate of $M$ is $\cos(\theta) $ ($\theta$ is the angle ${IOM}$ as you know) and its $y$ coordinate is $\sin(\theta)$.

But why is this true? Why isn't it the inverse?

Comment: This the definition: we **call** the $x$ coordinate of $M$ $\cos(\theta)$ and the $y$ coordinate of $M$ $\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane But why do we get the x coordinate of M by for example theta^2 or other function, why is it specifically cos(theta)?

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: The downvote is because you are putting no effort into understanding the answers given to you. As was already answered: For the point $M$, the $x$ coordinate is *defined* to be $\cos\theta$.  It can then easily be shown that $\cos\theta\neq\theta^2$, through the definition of $\cos$ introduced earlier.

Comment: @5xum I'm asking: why is this definition true? What's the intuition behind it?

Comment: The definition is not true, it just is. We *choose* to call *whatever* we get as the $x$ coordinate "$\cos\theta$".

Comment: @5xum In other words, why cos theta and sin theta will precisely determine to us where a point lies in the unit circle?

Comment: Because the $x$ and $y$ coordinate precisely determine where a point lies in the plane, and $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ equal the $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

Comment: @5xum why do they equal the x and y coordinates?

Comment: Because they are defined to equal $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

Comment: @5xum why couldn't I define them as tan theta for example

Comment: This cannot go on here. I advise you to ask your math teacher about this.

Comment: You can define them as tan theta. of course. But then your tan function (what you call "tan") will be **the very same function** everybody else calls $\cos$.

Comment: @5xum why would it be so?

Comment: Because you would take what everybody calls $\cos$ and you would say "I call this "$\tan$"". Then, no suprise, what you call $\tan$ would be exactly the same as what everybody else calls $\cos$.

Comment: @5xum How does everybody knows it is cos? Just see the answer given by the very clever and wise Emanuele Paolini

Comment: Yes, I guess she understood what you are trying to ask while I didn't. My fault, I guess. Though also yours for not posting a clear question.

Comment: @user138823: You should be aware that some settings *define* $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ as the coordinates of points on the circle, rather than in terms of triangles. And other settings *define* them in completely different ways as well. This back and forth is because you are asking "Why are the coordinates triangle-cosine and triangle-sine", and user138823 is telling you "circle-cosine and circle-sine are *defined* to be the coordinates". Incidentally, I suspect much of this confusino could have been avoided if you explained why you thought coordinates should be the other way around.

Comment: ... in mathematics, the circle-trig functions are more commonly used than the triangle-trig functions, since they have the same values for angles between $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$ (excluding the endpoints), but these are the only values where triangle-trig functions are defined, whereas the circle-trig functions are defined for *all* angle measures. (note that "triangle-sine" and "circle-sine" are not standard terms; there is rarely any need to distinguish between the two, so I had to invent my own words to describe this discussion)

Comment: (note that the triangle-trig functions are even inadequate for doing trigonometry with triangles, since sometimes $90^\circ$ degree angles are needed, or even angles between $90^\circ$ and $180^\circ$)

Comment: Aah! A correction to my previous comment: "circular trig functions" *are* standard terminology, to distinguish them from the "hyperbolic trig functions" (e.g. $\cosh$ and $\sinh$) which are based on the hyperbola and are different. However, "triangle trig functions" are not standard terminology, since as I already mentioned, there is rarely any need to actually refer to them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you got this definition:

The number $\cos \theta$ is defined as the ratio $IO/OM$ of a triangle $IOM$ which has a right angle at $I$ and angle $\theta$ at $O$.

Now if you take a unit circle in an orthogonal coordinate system centered in $O$ and take a point $M$ on the cirlce and project the point $M$ orthogonally on the line of the $x$-axis, you get a point $I$ such that the triangle $IOM$ has the properties stated above. In particular being $OM=1$ you get that $OI= \cos \theta$ and $OI$ is actually defined as the $x$ coordinate of the point $M$.

Comment: In particular, in mathematics we typically measure angles counterclockwise from the positive $x$-axis, which is why Emanuele constructed the particular triangle he did. Note you adopted a different convention -- e.g. measuring them clockwise from the positive $y$-axis, then the coordinates would indeed be the other way around.